# Removing a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to remove a function on a click event.

I have looked at the unbind and nullifying but I am unsure of the best solution, is there a destroy ability - I can't seem to find one. I need to be able to run the function again when I click `.button`

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    run();

    $('.back').on('click', '.back', function () {
        //remove the run function
    });
});

function run() {
    //code
}
```

I have also tried nullifying the function but it doesn't remove the event fully,

```
run = null;

run = function () {};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.unbind('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

Comment: what happens if he has other logic in that event beside the run function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.noop()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop):

```
run = $.noop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var isRun = 0;
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
   if(isRun == 0) {
    run();
} 
});
  $('body').on('click', '.back', function () {
       isRun = 1;
    });
function run() {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.back').on('click', '.back', function () {
        function run() {}//empty function will override original function on click
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer may work. If not, try this: `run().remove`